# Choose element affected by css in svg file by specifying an attribute instead of an element type

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to  change the visibility of some elements in an svg file using css.

I understand that you can select the type of shapes you want to modify with css by writing it type. e.g :

```
<style type="text/css" xml:space="preserve">
    <![CDATA[rect.rectClass {
        stroke: #000066;
        fill: #00cc00;
    }]]>
</style>
<rect x="330" width="100" y="77" height="100" class="rectClass"/>
```

In this example, the style css will be apply on the element rect, and on all others rect.

I would like to know if there is a way to **choose the elements** you want to alter **by specifying an attribute** contained in its tag **instead of specifying the type of the element**. e.g :

```
<style type="text/css" xml:space="preserve">
    <![CDATA[rect.layer.layerClass { // Instead of rect, I would like to
        stroke: #000066;             // put the groupType (layer) which is an attribute
        fill: #00cc00;               // of a shape
        visibility: hidden;
    }]]>
</style>
<rect x="330" width="100" y="77" height="100" groupType="layer" class="layerClass"/>
```

As you can see, the attributes groupType of the element rectangle is "layer", so I would like it to apply the css type for the element "rect.layer.layerClass" that I define.

The syntax is willingly false, because I do not know how to write it or even if it is possible to do that.

Do you think it is possible ?

************************ Edit *************************
Thanks to Dekel, here is the answer :

```
[groupType=layer].layerClass {
    stroke: #000066;
    fill: #00cc00;
}
```

Now I would like to know how I could do the same with a namespace. e.g :

Here is a full example, which does not work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           xmlns:toto="http://www.toto.com/tata" width="1000"
                height="1000" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.0">
    <style type="text/css" xml:space="preserve">
        <![CDATA[[toto:/groupType=layer].layerClass {
            visibility:hidden;
        }]]>
    </style>
    <defs>
    <rect toto:groupType="layer" x="330" width="100" y="77" height="100" class="layerClass"/>
    </svg>
```

But it did not worked. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this selector for that: `[groupType=layer]`

```css
[groupType=layer].layerClass {
  stroke: #000066;
  fill: #00cc00;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <rect x="330" width="100" y="77" height="100" groupType="layer" class="layerClass"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome ! Works like a charm. Do you know if there is a namespace, all I have to do is change "[groupType].layerClass" by "[ns:groupType].layerClass" ? I tried but it did not work.

Comment: You can try `[ns\:groupType].layerClass`. It should work.

Comment: Here is what I did  (supposed that my namespace is     xmlns:toto=""http://www.toto.com/tata") :
    [toto\:groupType=layer].layerClass {...}
But it did not work. Is my syntax wrong ?

Comment: StackOverflow does not allowed url... supposed that it is written with the right syntax before "toto.com/tata"

Comment: add a jsfiddle example... don't code inside comments

Comment: well, if the answer is correct I will appreciate if you can accept it and voteup :)

Comment: And regarding the namespace - add a complete SVN code

Comment: I add a complete example file. I will accept your ansewer if you can help to find a solution for the namespace.

Comment: I cannot, my company block the link you sent me... Is it so complicated that you can't post it here ?

Comment: You know... it really makes no sense. I really don't mind helping you here, but You asked a question, got a solution, and now you want to have an answer to a different question before accepting the original answer...

Comment: Your question was styling SVG based on attribute. I think you got the answer here...

Comment: It is not completely different from the original question. I thank you for your help, but you did not completely solved my problem. I cannot accept your answer now, otherwise I will not receive help anymore on my question.

Comment: Actually what you could do is open a new question (which is **different** from the original you posted here).

Comment: Just for your information - this kind of behavior doesn't really encourage people to help, and you are the one who is seeking for help here :)